# how to broadcast sms through iPhone apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms, imessage

is it  possible to send n number of sms to n number of user and i want to collect the all the reply also in iPhone .i don't have any idea to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the SMS app in your phone with a prefilled text from your app, and send it from there, but you can't read your SMS in your app or send them from inside your app.

Comment: i want to implement this task in my apps

Comment: What task? I just told you you can't do exactly what you want to do

Comment: means via apps i want to send ams and want to receive if user replied .

Comment: You can't, you can't send an sms from your app and reply to it, the only thing you can do is open the sms composer of the phone with a prefilled text

Comment: use off any service provider  it is  possible or not .do have any idea

Comment: If another provider provides a service to send a SMS from a Webservice, for example, you can use it, but you still can't read the SMS received in your phone from your app.

Answer (score 0):

from your application you can send n no.of SMS to n no.of people. but you can't get replied SMS to your app. Apple have a restriction to this. If you want how to send SMS from app let me know

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>


-(void)composeSMS

{

  MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

                if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])

                {
                    controller.body =@"Testing";
                    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
                    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
                }
}

-(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result

{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: i want send the sms and want to receive if user replied

Comment: and how can i send n no.of SMS to n no.of people help me @charan giro

Comment: @giri use of my apps i want to send sms .where have i type the no of receiver user in this code give some more information

Comment: add     controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1(234)567-8910", nil];
here you can set no of people you need to SMS/Messege